# Posting data from iphone server with help http

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to post the data from iphone
for that use the code like this

```
 -(void)sendRequest

    {

        NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
        //Create the dateformatter object
        NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        //Set the required date format
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
        //Get the string date
        NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

        ; ****i am getting the  warning 'NSData' may not respond to '- autorelease]; 


        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        if (theConnection) {
            webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            NSLog(@"%@",webData);

        }



}
```

And  it get crash and show the   **-[NSConcreteMutableData setLength:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xdde2760**

this updata code

```
-(void)sendRequest

{

    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    //Create the dateformatter object
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    //Set the required date format
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS"];
    //Get the string date
    NSString* str = [formatter stringFromDate:date];



    if (theConnection) {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
        NSLog(@"%@",webData);

    }

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{   
    [webData setLength: 0]; 
} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{         
    [webData appendData:data]; 

} 

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{     
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 

} 

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{      
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus);  
    [loginStatus release];           
    [connection release];  
    [webData release]; 
}
```

Comment: Change  NSData *post  to NSString *post. Also have you written the delegate methods? I think you haven't.

Comment: As error is shows NSConcreteMutableData seems that your problem is with webData. so check all the places where you are releasing webData. if possible use [[NSMutableData data] init].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You a having `warning` there because you are assigning object of class `NSString` to `NSData`, look here:

```
NSData *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token=%@&JourneyID=%@&JourneyName=%@&Locationname=%@&StartDate=%@&Distance=%@&ShareType=%@&LastSyncDate=%@",tokenapi,Journey_ID,Journey_Name,Location_Name,Start_Date,Dist,Share_type,str];
```

So first of all try to replace it with

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Token=%@&JourneyID=%@&JourneyName=%@&Locationname=%@&StartDate=%@&Distance=%@&ShareType=%@&LastSyncDate=%@",tokenapi,Journey_ID,Journey_Name,Location_Name,Start_Date,Dist,Share_type,str];
```

Comment: But even i am getting the app getting crash what was the problem where i am getting wrong

Comment: On what line is app crashing?

Comment: I think that problem is in method `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`. Please, show me your code of that method

Comment: Edit your question and post it here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3167/discussion-between-nekto-and-harish)

Answer (score 1):

```
I think below code help you
NSString *soapMessage=postString;//Your string

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        //NSLog(@"%@", data);
        NSString *filename = @"filename";
        NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR-URL"]];
        [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
        [data release];
        [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [theRequest setHTTPBody:postbody];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
        if( theConnection ){
            myWebData=[[NSMutableData alloc]  initWithLength:0];
        }
```

Comment: NSString *filename = @"filename" what should i write over here

Comment: no need to write anything .this date stores at server side with this file name and in temp directory .k

Comment: is that compulsory to use this

Answer (score 0):

Your first and most obvious problem is that you have decalred post to be of type NSData* but are assignining it to a NSString*.

Secondly you probably need to start the url connection at some point otherwise nothing will happen.

I *strongly* recommend using the [ASI library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for you http requests. It will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Now the warning is gone but the data even not get post on to server it show me html page in console

Answer (score 0):

You have set your NSMutableRequest to autorelease. This may be the reason it's crashing as it's being released before you want it to. Get rid of that and instead manually release it ([request release[) after your if(theConnection). This may fix the crash.

Have you set the functions for handling the connection ? As this isn't in your question ...

Comment: It doesn't matter. Autorelease means when it goes out of scope, in other words reference count is zero. Hence it will be retained in the entire scope of the method.

Comment: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] retain]; if (theConnection) {
  webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  NSLog(@"%@",webData);
  
 }
[request release]; but even it get crash

Comment: True, I would still release it manually to free the memory though :)

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

Then you can addValue to "theRequest"


[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];


if( theConnection )
 {
blah blah

Comment: Then you need you connection Handlers:


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
 
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
 
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
// NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");
    
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take ownership of the object at this particular point.

```
postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]
```

using retain/copy properties...

Remember that you explicitly have to take ownership for returned objects from methods that contain neither new, alloc, retain or copy in their name as they return autoreleased instances.

Hope this will help you ...

Comment: i was also getting the same error like this....
-[NSConcreteMutableData setLength:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xdde2760
this line is just setting a very large string to an NSData object.

So for this you need to take ownership of the object: like i'm giving example...

my error was coming in the following code: 
liveDataWork = [liveData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

for this i have to take ownership of the object:

at that time i only changed in the code was...

self.liveDataWork = [liveData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

by used self.liveDataWork it works...

Comment: i didn't get you?check the above code make point where should make change

Answer (score 0):

As I said on the chat, you should do the submit with ASIFormDataRequest class instead of the NSMutableURLRequest, because it is much easier and it is well tested and it has a good documentation [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).